Could i connect to Kafka Cluster through domain?
Have a nice day, guys.
Recently, I've been studying Apache Kafka using the "Kafka: The Definitive Guide" book.
While setting up and experimenting with Kafka, I realized it was putting a significant strain on my MacBook's resources. So, I decided to run my Kafka cluster on my server and use my existing domain to connect.
Here’s my current setup:

I have a dedicated server with a static public IP.
I use Cloudflare to manage DNS for my domain.
For reverse proxy and SSL management, I rely on Nginx Proxy Manager.

The challenge:
Since Kafka uses TCP protocol for its communication (not HTTP/HTTPS), I’m trying to figure out how to properly route and expose my Kafka brokers through the domain (kafka.domain.com). My goal is to enable external clients (e.g., my local development machine) to connect to the Kafka cluster using this domain, as shown below:
kafka cluster connect i want
but external clients fail to connect to kafka cluster, and i suspect there might be misconfigurations in my kafka setup or the reverse proxy.
i'm not sure if this is the correct approach to expose Kafka using a domain in this way. if anyone is familiar with this setup, it would be great if you could provide some guidance or share a relevant Github link that demonstrates a similar configuration. Or if you know some tutorial to solve my questions, it also thank you
Thank you for reading my questions!
i tried changing kafka advertised listener, setting nginx stream through nginx proxy manager, changing springboot application.yml, toggle cloudflare dns mode(DNS Only).
but it doesnt work.... i need some advice..
